# Call apex class method immediate after input text

Tags: visualforce, javascript, actionsupport, autocomplete

I have below code where after I do enter an auto complete input text value I need to click elsewhere for the apex class method {!applyfiler} to work. But I need to call that method instantly after input text value enterred without any further click. Can someone please help me here?

**Apex page code**

```
 <apex:pageblockSectionItem > 
       <apex:outputText rendered="{!userType == 'Admin' || userType == 'HomeOffice' || userType == 'Field'}">Compliance Incident Transaction Name</apex:outputText>
            <apex:inputText styleClass="apexCITautocomplete" value="{!selectedCIT}" id="Rep">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!applyfiler}" rerender="pb"/>
     </apex:inputtext> 
    </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
```

Comment: I think you can use `onKeyPress` event, but why would you want to call a method like this? If there is a query or a DML you will very likely to hit the limits and break everything

Comment: What could be an alternative? Can you please let me know if somehow by javascript that possible?

Comment: I think that you should apply the "onkeyup" event to your action support.

Comment: I can't find such example, trying out that in google.

Comment: I see that you are building and autocomplete component. You can use `onkeypress` or `onkeyup` instead of `onchange` event. I think you should use an actionfunction and call it only when user has typed 2 or more characters. OR you can use a pre-built component  [Autocomplete v2](http://blogforce9.blogspot.in/2013/10/auto-complete-visualforce-component-v2.html)

Comment: Funny I was just typing an answer with the same remark :)

Comment: Just now I tried that but without actionsupport it's not working. Please find my attempt below.

Comment: <apex:pageblockSectionItem > 
       <apex:outputText rendered="{!userType == 'Admin' || userType == 'HomeOffice' || userType == 'Field'}">Representative Name</apex:outputText>
            <apex:inputText styleClass="apexRepautocomplete" value="{!selectedRep}" onkeyup="applyfiler()" id="Rep">
    
     </apex:inputtext> 
    </apex:pageblockSectionItem>

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script> 
window.$j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
$j(document).ready(function(){ 
$j('input[id$=Rep]').on('input', function () { 
   applyfilter($j(this).val());
}); 
}); 

</script>

<apex:actionfunction action="{!applyfiler}" name="applyfilter" rerender="pb">
  <apex:param assignto="{!selectedCIT}" name="param1" value="">
</apex:actionfunction>
<apex:pageblockSection>
<apex:pageblockSectionItem > 
       <apex:outputText rendered="{!userType == 'Admin' || userType == 'HomeOffice' || userType == 'Field'}">Compliance Incident Transaction Name</apex:outputText>
            <apex:inputText styleClass="apexCITautocomplete" value="{!selectedCIT}" id="Rep">
     </apex:inputtext> 
    </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
```

Comment: It calls the method before I complete entering the input text. Thus showing erroneous result. Both onkeyup and onkeypress works kind of similar fashion.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to do that using Javascript function? I have no depth knowledge in javascript but I think that could be the perfect way.

Comment: I found a start for your problem with JQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105997/javascript-change-event-on-input-element-fires-on-only-losing-focus

Comment: Yes this exactly is the case but how may I use this?

Comment: You have to include the JQuery script. Then bind your event with JQuery like in my previous link. Then in the change event, call your apex method like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047775/call-a-controller-method-from-javascript-in-visualforce

Comment: I tried but can't do that. Not so good in javascript. Can you please help my case?

Comment: Ok I edited my answer with a try. I'm not so good in Javascript neither.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51227/discussion-between-sfdc-learner-and-martin-lezer).

Answer (score 2):

You can use onKeyPress, as said. But you may want to consider to make it smarter than making a SOQL query on each key that was pressed. For example using javascript you can wait to make a call (remote action) until 3 characters are added.

If the size of the table you are quering allows it you can then select all that start with those 3 characters.

ex: SELECT Name FROM Object__c WHERE Name Like 'abc%' and do further filtering client-side.

In this case you have only 1 SOQL query.

Comment: @Nielson.   
It calls the method before I complete entering the input text. Thus showing erroneous result. Both onkeyup and onkeypress works kind of similar fashion.

Comment: What kind of result are you getting? Onkeypress you should execute the query and bind it to your autocomplete list. If the usermeanwhile typed more charachters you should filter the result list based on those characters (or block typing while you refresh the list using the query)

Comment: Did you checkout the package that someone added to the comments of your question? Sounds like you can just steal a bit from their implementation: http://blogforce9.blogspot.be/2013/10/auto-complete-visualforce-component-v2.html

Comment: Before I do select the input text value from the suggestions, onkeypress or onkeyup calls the method. Hence my selected value is not sent. Thus causing wrong results.

Comment: Yes looking into it. But I don't think adding component will at all be permissible here.  :(

Comment: Checked their demo. This is not my case. Here they need to click the submit button after selecting a value inorder to get some ID. In my case there is no submit button and method call is instant. :(